# Wild half-line in a Euclidean space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Is there an $m$-dimensional simplicial complex $S$ with the following properties:

- *The cone over $S$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{E}^{m+1}$.* Here $\mathbb{E}^{m+1}$ denoes the $(m+1)$-dimensional Euclidean space.
- *There is a vertex $v$ in $S$ such that the complement $S\backslash\{v\}$ is not simply connected.*

**Comments.**

- If such example exist, the cone over $v$ has to from a wild half-line in the Euclidean space. It has to be an embedding of $[0,\infty)$ which complement is not simply connected.
- The first condition is equivalent to the following: *The spherical suspension over $S$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{m+1}$.*

Comment: Btw do you define the cone of $X$ from $X\times [0,1]$ by crushing $X\times\{0\}$ to a point, or from $X\times [0,+\infty\mathclose[$?

Comment: @YCor the cone is infinite.

Comment: OK... So passing to the 1-point compactification, it yields a sphere in which the complement of some segment is not simply connected.

Comment: In the comment you might say that the embedding of the half-line is proper .

Comment: Subquestion: does there exist a simplicial complex, homeomorphic to some sphere, and in which there exists an injective combinatorial path (= some consecutive edge with no return) whose complement is not simply connected?

Comment: @YCor The double suspension over Poincaré sphere is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^5$. The complement of the double-suspension-equator in it is not simply connected.

Comment: What is "double suspension equator"?

Comment: @YCor double suspension over $X$ is the joint $\mathbb{S}^1*X$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$ is its equator.

Comment: So, I don't understand your comment. The "double-suspension-equator" is not an injective combinatorial path, is it?

Comment: @YCor it is a 1-dimensional subcomplex in the triangulation coming from the suspension, but (by obvious reason) it is not subcomplex in the standard triangulation of sphere.

Comment: I was asking about an injective path, not an injective loop.

Comment: @YCor, but the answer is the same.

Comment: I can believe so, but I haven't grasped the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got the following answer from Alexander Lytchak:

An example can be constructed the following way.
Start with a nontrivial homology sphere,
pass to its spherical suspension.
Now shrink one of the meridians of suspension to the point, which we denote by $v$.
The obtained space $S$ is the example;
it admits a natural triangulation.

The first condition is easy to check.
To check the second condition note that the spherical suspension $\Sigma(S)$ has a triangulation coming from $S$.

The space $\Sigma(S)$ is a homotopy equivalent to the sphere;
it is homological manifold 
which is also manifold everywhere except maybe the poles of suspension.
Each pole admits a simply connected punctured neighborhood.
Therefore by disjoint disc property the poles are also manifold point.
It remains to apply generalized Poincaré conjecture.

Comment: You start with a homology sphere of dimension $(m-1)$, so that $S$ is $m$-dimensional (and its cone is $(m+1)$-dimensional). So it gives examples for every $m\ge 4$. For $m\le 3$, do you know whether it's impossible? ($m\le 1$ is trivial, $m=2$ is probably easy but I'm not sure for $m=3$)

Comment: @YCor I do not know --- I guess there are no examples for $m\le 3$. Anyway I am happy with this one --- it solves all my problems.